# Iteration on lazy map implementation with fixed key set

Tags: java, collections, maps, lazy-loading

I'm working on a project where I need a **lazy map** that generates values on demand based on a **fixed key set**. Both whether a key is in the key set and the value associated to a key shall only be computed on demand.

Without a fixed key set, `map.containsKey(key)` only returns `true` if a value for the key has been computed and added to the map before (via calling `get(key)`). This is not the desired behavior - `map.containsKey(key)` should return `true` if the key is part of the key set.

An example key set would be all integers from `0` to `1.000`. I do not want to fill the map with all keys until it is necessary (e.g. because of an `map.containsValue(value)` call). The key set itself is easy to calculate, but I only want to fill the map if necessary to save memory. It is also simple to find out whether a key should be contained in the set.

---

Using a wrapper around an existing `HashMap`, I created an implementation that fulfills the above requirements.

#### Example `map.containsKey(key)` implementation:

```
private final Map<Integer, String> intern = new HashMap<>();

@Override
public synchronized boolean containsKey(Object key) {
    if (intern.containsKey(key)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        if (key instanceof Integer) {
            Integer i = (Integer) key;
            boolean contained = isKeyInKeySet(i);
            if (contained) {
                intern.put(i, null);
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

(Note that `map.get(key)` computes values that are `null`.)

**I can't get iterations on the collection views of the map** (`map.keySet()`, `map.values()` and `map.entrySet()`) **to work.** How do I adapt the default `Iterator` to also include all values in the key set - even if they are not part of the map yet?

Comment: For what it's worth: Guava used to have this, and discovered that the violations of the `Map` contract made too many things too screwed up, and got rid of it.  I strongly advise against trying to squeeze this behavior into the `Map` contract, and recommend writing a new interface for this specific sort of behavior instead.

Comment: If the `Map` does not yet know what it contains, how would an `Iterator` know?

Comment: @Bobulous I want the `Iterator` to first iterate through all already in the map existing keys, and then (if necessary) through all keys that are included in the key set, but not yet in the map. This way entries to the map are only made if a key is actually used at least once.

Comment: Okay, but where is the set of keys not yet in the map? Your code snippet does not show a data object for this. And how do you populate this key set in the first place, where does the data come from?